# How do I use a variable from another file?

Tags: php, relative-path, web-development-server

I wanted to call a variable from nuclear_test2.php by nuclear_test.php

[image]

I have unsuccessfully tried the following calls as stated below:

```
//include_once("../test/nuclear_test2.php");
//include_once("nuclear_test2.php");
//include_once("./test/nuclear_test2.php");
//require_once("./nuclear_test2.php");
```

nuclear_test.php

```
<?php 
require "nuclear_test2.php";

 function acheckReturner() {
        echo   " ?" .  $check;
}
    acheckReturner();
?>
```

nuclear_test2.php

```
<?php
    $check = " ooooooooo";
?>
```

Comment: Any comment would be welcome. Please help if you can. Thanks to stackoverflow for creating such a helpful community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the `include` or `require`. The problem is that `$check` is not defined inside your `acheckReturner` function.

```
<?php 
require "nuclear_test2.php";

function acheckReturner() {
    echo   " ?" .  $check; // this $check is undefined in this scope
}
acheckReturner();
?>
```

You can use it by passing it as an argument to the `acheckReturner` function.

```
<?php 
require "nuclear_test2.php";

function acheckReturner($check) {
    echo   " ?" .  $check;
}

acheckReturner($check); // this is the $check from nuclear_test2.php
?>
```

The [PHP documentation on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) may be helpful.

Comment: what can i tell u? sir/mam. U have just saved me hours of pain, frustration of failure, enjoyment of failure, and time.